# How can I attach outlook mail banners / tags

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server

Im looking for ways to add mail headers so the mail recipients will be able to identify that the message is a spam -  such as the banner that exists in the screenshot below. Do I need to use the X-Antispam message headers? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/SecurityCompliance/anti-spam-message-headers

[image]

Comment: Please clarify - do you want _your_ messages to be seen as Spam by your recipients? Who is "the user" in your question?

Comment: thanks, @tum_ the user is the mailbox owner that is the recipient of the given mail - I would like the message to be seen as spam by the mail recipients

Comment: I don't have the answer but here is what I think - using X-Antispam headers might work or not depending on whether the Exchange server keeps them intact or strips before inserting its own Antispam headers. This can be checked by an experiment. I bet you can achieve your goal in a simpler way by just faking the 'From' address, setting it to some spammer's email (like fgrtr85646gd-747474glksvd@mail.ru) :) In any case, there's not much you can do if your email is in the 'white list' of the recipient.